# How to create situational or job specific test program flows?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am wondering how folks create situational or test program specific test program flows based on silicon feedback data.  I see that their are job based flows talked about in these videos:

http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/5-create-program-flow/
http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/6-create-program-tests/

How do folks use silicon test results to alter their flows without putting brittle condition based test exclusions (e.g. next if test == 'mytest')?  I guess I would say there are at least this many jobs or scenarios:

- debug (aka first silicon)
- samples (can be multiple)
- characterization (can be multiple)
- ttr (can be multiple)
- quality assurance (all tests or perhaps a specific quality flow like HTOL or HTOL time-zero)

Is there a way to pass in silicon based test names to prevent having to alter flows all of the time?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `if/unless_enable` controls are for: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flowapi/#Execution_Based_on_the_Runtime_Environment

This creates what are called user flags (I think) on V93K, which are designed to be set by the "user" before the flow is executed and not really change state during execution. As opposed to flow flags which can be changed at runtime by tests during the flow execution.

`if/unless_job` is a similar user flag that is intended to indicate the insertion in the test flow (e.g. wafer test 1, wafer test 2, etc) and is inspired by the column/attribute of the same name on Teradyne platforms. On V93K it generates a regular user flag called `@JOB`.

The three different types of controls you have then are:

`if/unless_job` - Use to model the test insertion name, normally this naming would be something that you would want all of your test modules to agree on - you can't really have module specific values for this. e.g. `WT1`, `WT2`, `FTR`, `FTH`, etc.

`if/unless_enable` - Option switches to be set at the start of the flow to enable/disable different parts of the flow. These can either be very specific to a particular test module, or common to the whole flow, or a mixture of both. e.g. `SAMPLES`, `TTR`, `SRAM_CZ` etc.

`if/unless_flag` - To respond to flags which can be changed at runtime, normally depending on the result of a particular test(s).

Finally, the enables are usually set by either the test floor controller software, or they can be set within the flow itself, depending on the platform and local conventions.

If you want to enable/disable these flags within the flow itself then Origen provides the following API:

```rb
enable :samples

if_enable :samples do
  test :test1  # Will be hit due to the samples flag being set
end

disable :samples

if_enable :samples do
  test :test1  # Now it won't be
end
```

Comment: is there a way to set a flag disable in the options to the Flow.create method call?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be 'disable :samples' and 'enable :samples'?

Comment: You can create a startup method in your interface to intercept and apply such options - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_app_generators/blob/master/templates/app_generators/test_engineering/test_block/lib/interface.rb