# Setting the current test insertion within the DUT model

Tags: origen-sdk

We have evolved our Origen usage such that we have a params file and a flow file for each test module (scan, mbist, etc.).  We are now at the point where we need to take into account the test insertion when handling the DUT model and the test flow generation.  I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158438/how-to-create-situational-or-job-specific-test-program-flows) that using a job flag is the preferred method for specifying test insertion specifics into the flow file.  And this [video](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/5-create-program-flow/) shows how to specify a test insertion when simulating the test flow.  My question is how can a test insertion be specified when not generating a flow, only loading params files into the DUT model?  Take this parameter set that defines some test conditions for a scan/ATPG test module.

```
  scan.define_params :test_flows do |p|
    p.flows.ws1.chain = [:vmin, :vmax]
    p.flows.ft1.chain = [:vmin, :vmax]
    p.flows.ws1.logic = [:vmin, :vmax]
    p.flows.ft1.logic = [:vmin]
    p.flows.ws1.delay = [:pmax]
    p.flows.ft1.delay = [:pmin]
  end
```

You can see in the parameter set hierarchy that there are two test insertions defined: 'ws1' and 'ft1'.  Am I right to assume that the `--job` option only sets a flag somewhere when used with the `origen testers:run` command?  Or can this option be applied to `origen i`, such that just loading some parameter sets will have access to the job selected?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do what you want here, but given that you are using parameters in this example the way I would do it would be to align your parameter contexts to the job name:

```rb
scan.define_params :ws1 do |p|
  p.flows.chain = [:vmin, :vmax]
  p.flows.logic = [:vmin, :vmax]
  p.flows.delay = [:pmax]
end

scan.define_params :ft1 do |p|
  p.flows.chain = [:vmin, :vmax]
  p.flows.logic = [:vmin]
  p.flows.delay = [:pmin]
end
```

There are various ways to actually set the current context, one way would be to have a target setup per job:

```rb
# target/ws1.rb
MyDUT.new
dut.params = :ws1

# target/ft1.rb
MyDUT.new
dut.params = :ft1
```

Here it is assuming that the scan object is configured to track the context of the top-level DUT - http://origen-sdk.org/origen//guides/models/parameters/#Tracking_the_Context_of_Another_Object

Comment: thanks @Ginty.  I used your suggestion of aligning my contexts to the test insertion and then just sniffed the command line options looking for --job, which I used to then set the DUT parameter context.